# PyQt5 Threading a Selenium Script

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I'm having difficulties figuring out threading in PyQt5. I made a GUI for a script I use at work in order to share with my coworker. The script does selenium browser automation with some variables that it receives from the GUI. The script is located in a different .py file and it doesn't inherit from any class I just instantiate it in the mainapp.py when I click the query button. (Oh and the script doesn't return anything, I added a return True for testing purposes)

mainapp.py

```
class OutputCheckerSub(Ui_OutputChecker):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    ........
    ........

    # Connecting Query button
    self.query_button.clicked.connect(self.run_output_script)

def run_output_script(self):
    self.output_script.run_script()

    ......
```

This launches the script with the proper variables but crashes the GUI app.

I managed to get threading somewhat working (W/O setting the variables) but it crashes after 10 seconds.

multithreading.py

```
class OutputScriptThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        output_checker_script = output_checker.OutputCheckerScript()
        state = output_checker_script.run_script()
        self.signal.emit(state)
```

mainapp.py with faulty threading

```
class OutputCheckerSub(Ui_OutputChecker):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        .......
        .......
        # Connecting Query button
        self.query_button.clicked.connect(self.run_output_script)
        self.outputcheck_thread = multithreading.OutputScriptThread()

    def run_output_script(self):
        self.outputcheck_thread.start()

    .....
```

One more challenging part is passing variables from one class to another. currently my GUI directly modifies the variables of the instanciated script . If I get the threading working where should I set the variables ? From the Thread?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Have you tried the Gooey library? It's a really easy way to make UIs in just one decorator. Might solve your problem a lot faster than figuring out QT theads.